# What is the correct adjective suffix form for tropism?

Tags: adjectives, american-english, syntactic-analysis

A tropism is a type of biological response where an organism reacts to a particular environmental stimulus. For instance, try searching for gravitropism or phototropism and you'll see what I mean.

I'd like to refer to something as being of a **tropical** nature, to mean that something has the characteristic of being a tropism. But it doesn't sound well to me, because I'm used to see the word tropical refer to something related to the tropics.

Is **tropical** the correct syntax for the adjective form of tropism?

Shouldn't it be **tropismal** instead?

Comment: Examples: Most bioreactors have focused on the growth of *phototropic* species.An *isotropic* medium is one such that the permittivity, ε, and permeability, μ, of the medium are uniform in all directions of the medium, the simplest instance being free space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Trop-* basically means "turn", and *tropism* is presumably named after the way e.g. sunflowers turn towards the sun (they do, don't they?). So the most basic adjective would be **tropic**, "pertaining to turning". That is my recommendation: it is short, it is a proper translation, it is properly formed, and it is not in use much as an adjective. And it appears to be already used to refer to tropism as a suffix in many words (*-tropic*).

> the flower displayed a tropic response to sunlight

You could use *tropical*, which would be the same, except that it lacks shortness and it is in use as an adjective meaning something else (the tropics are the circles where the sun "turns" in December and June after having moved away from the equator for a few months, the sun's "location" being understood as that area of the earth's surface that is closest to the sun at mid-day, if I am not mistaken).

*Tropismal* is possible, and correct, but long. And it is not used in this sense, or at all, so far as I know. The same applies to *tropist*, another legitimate form.

P.S. I would not recommend *gravitropic*, because it is a hybrid of Latin (gravis) and Greek (tropeô/trepô). A proper and commonly used Greek suffix meaning "heavy" is *bar(y)-*, resulting in *barotropic*, turning towards that which is heavy. However, it appears this word is already in use in a different sense, one related to *bar(y)-* in the sense of "heavy, pressing upon something", meaning "characterized by or associated with an atmospheric condition in which surfaces of constant pressure coincide with those of constant density". The word *geotropic*, "earth-turning", as suggested by Sumelic, is a very nice word that is actually so used.

Comment: Actually, *geotropism* seems to be an existing synonym using all-Greek roots. The OED defines it as "The directional growth of a plant or (less commonly) a sessile animal in response to gravity; (also) the directional movement of a motile animal in response to gravity (= geotaxis n.); an instance of any of these responses." The OED defines *barotropic* as "  Characterized by or associated with an atmospheric condition in which surfaces of constant pressure coincide with those of constant density." So that's a possible clash of definitions.

Comment: @sumelic: That is actually quite a nice word, turning towards the earth. Might not work any more once we colonise Mars, though. We'll have to vary between geotropic and areotropic, then...

Comment: @sumelic: I have incorporated your excellent comment into my answer.

Comment: @Cerberus: funny! Like French [*alunir*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/alunir/2624) and the hypothetical *amarsir* I've seen in a few places. But I think that if we can study Martian ***geo**logy* and ***geo**graphy*, we can also have ***geo**tropic* plants on Mars :)

Comment: @sumelic: Ah, another very nice word, alunir! Martian "geology", are you mad? I'm sure the g-word will be the "nigger" of our Martian descendants!

Answer (score 2):

Searching the Oxford Learner's dictionaries, I found the following words listed:

[phototropism](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/phototropism?q=phototropism):

> BrE /ˌfəʊtəʊˈtrəʊpɪzəm/, NAmE /ˌfoʊtoʊˈtroʊpɪzəm/
>   
> the action of a plant turning towards or away from light

[phototropic](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/phototropic):

> BrE /ˌfəʊtəʊˈtrɒpɪk/, NAmE /ˌfoʊtoʊˈtrɑːpɪk/
>   
> (of a plant or how it grows) turning towards or away from light

There are no entries for "phototropical" or "phototropismal"; it looks like these are not commonly used.

The OED has the following to say about the noun ending *-tropism* in general:

> **Pronunciation:** Brit. /ˈtrəʊpɪz(ə)m/ , U.S. /ˈtroʊˌpɪzəm/
>   [...]
>
> 1. Chem. Forming nouns denoting types of variation or change in structural or physical properties, as allotropism n., monotropism n., morphotropism n., etc. Usually corresponding to adjectives in -tropic *comb. form* and nouns in -trope *comb. form.*
>      Freq. with parallel formations in -tropy *comb. form.*
> 2. Chiefly Bot. Forming nouns denoting forms of directional movement or growth in response to a stimulus, as geotropism *n.*, phototropism *n.*, etc. Usually corresponding to adjectives in -tropic *comb. form.*
> 3. Pathol. Forming nouns denoting the tendency of a pathogen to infect a specific type of tissue, as neurotropism *n.*, viscerotropism *n.* at viscero- *comb. form* 2. Usually corresponding to adjectives in -tropic *comb. form.*

You can see that for all three listed uses, the corresponding adjectives generally use *-tropic*.